# Sending mail with INDY/DELPHI , modify values without restrictions

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm sending E Mails with INDY 10 components with the following code :

```
  try
    MyNewIndyMessage.From.Address := edFrom.Text;
    MyNewIndyMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := edTo.Text;
    MyNewIndyMessage.CCList.EMailAddresses := edCC.Text;
    MyNewIndyMessage.BCCList.EMailAddresses := edBCC.Text;
    MyNewIndyMessage.Subject := edSubject.Text;
    MyNewIndyMessage.Body := edContent.Lines;
    MyIndySMTP.Send(MyNewIndyMessage);
  finally
    MyIndySMTP.Disconnect;
  end;
```

Indy smtp requests me to enter a valid organisation in the Message.from.address like "myname@companyX.com" , I wouöld like to enter here and arbitray string like "This mail is urgent to read".
Can I bypass such check done in my INDY SMTP components ?

Comment: No. And you shouldn't if you could; most mail servers would reject your mail anyway, and most spam blocking software would block it as well.

Comment: From.Address must contain a valid mail address, but From.Name can contain whatever you like ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Internet Message Format specification (RFC 2822), the From field must contain a valid mailbox, which *normally* is (section 3.4):

> Normally, a mailbox is comprised of two parts: (1)
>      an optional display name that indicates the name of the recipient
>      (which could be a person or a system) that could be displayed to the
>      user of a mail application, and (2) an addr-spec address enclosed in
>      angle brackets ("<" and ">").  There is also an alternate simple form
>      of a mailbox where the addr-spec address appears alone, without the
>      recipient's name or the angle brackets.

An example of this may be like this:

```
John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
```

As implied, mail clients usually display the (optional) name attribute if present, and the address itself if a name is not present.

In INDY terms, the TIdEMailAddressItem have three properties, which are always in sync:

- `Address` is the address-spec part of the mailbox, for example: `john.doe@example.com`
- `Name` is the name part of the mailbox, for example: `John Doe`
- `Text` have both parts, for example: `John Doe <john.doe@example.com>`

You can change one of that and the others will reflect the same changes.

So, you can do what you want by setting the Text property directly, like this:

```
MyNewIndyMessage.From.Text := 'This mail is urgent to read <myname@companyX.com>';
```

Or you may want to set each one separately:

```
MyNewIndyMessage.From.Address := 'myname@companyX.com';
MyNewIndyMessage.From.Name := 'This mail is urgent to read';
```

All this said, you may want to use that *name* as the subject (along with some more info), and not really as the name, but that's up to you.

Comment: @Remy thanks for the edit, I didn't noticed I crossed the address/name and the address was lost in the Text part!